# Find every combination meeting constraints

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, combinations

I have a data frame of records with a date and "group".  I would like to find every combination of records which satisfies the constraints of:

1. There is one and only one record from each group.
2. Each record within the combination has a distinct date.
3. All records within a combination are within x days of each other.

My data is small enough that I should be able to find **every** combination.  If I can apply the constraints while creating the combinations it should keep the size manageable.  But so far I've only been able to create all combinations and then filter, which is very slow.

I'm guessing `data.table` would be useful?  Below is a MRE:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)

#Set some parameters to be used later
n_rows <- 1000
n_elig_groups <- 4
max_date_diff <- 8


#Create a data frame with id, date & group
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:n_rows,
  date = sample(seq.Date(ymd(20230101), ymd(20231231), by = "day"),
                n_rows,
                replace = TRUE),
  group = rep(letters, length.out = n_rows)
)


#What are the eligible groups?
elig_groups <- letters[sample(1:26, n_elig_groups)]


#Find every combination of records within the eligible groups where:
  #There is one and only one record from each group.
  #Each record within the combination has a distinct date.
  #All records within a combination are within x days of each other.


#Bad approach: this is technically correct but super inefficient

#Create every possible combination of records within the eligible groups
combos <- df %>% 
  filter(group == elig_groups[1]) %>% 
  select(-group) %>% 
  rename_all(function(x){paste0(x, "_", elig_groups[1])})
for(group_i in elig_groups[-1]){
  combos <- combos %>% 
    expand_grid({
      df %>% 
        filter(group == group_i) %>% 
        select(-group) %>% 
        rename_all(function(x){paste0(x, "_", group_i)})
    })
}

#Now find the combinations which meet our constraints
valid_combos <- combos %>% 
  #First, pivot to get a row for every record
  mutate(combo_id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-combo_id,
               names_to = c(".value", "group"),
               names_sep = "_") %>% 
  #Apply our constraints by combo
  group_by(combo_id) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(date) == n_elig_groups,
         max(date) - min(date) <= max_date_diff) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: What about combinations that are subsets of other valid combinations? Say records 1, 2, and 3 met the constraints. Would you want {1, 2}, {1, 3}, and {2, 3} in addition to {1, 2, 3}?

Comment: Another question: can we rely upon the groups having a regular pattern, like in the example, or are they random?

Comment: also, do you want 1. the ID combinations, 2. the date combinations, 3, dates and the number of different ways of making that combination, or 4. each individual row as a combination

Comment: @jblood94 I only want combinations that have exactly one record from each group.  So in the example when we're looking at 4 groups, each combination should have one record from each of the four groups and all combinations would have four records.

Comment: @Mark pretend the groups don't have a regular pattern.  The output should be the ID combinations, something like `tibble(combo_id = rep(1, 4), id = c(3, 5, 8, 13))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form valid combination affiliations with a `data.table` non-equi join on the dates followed by filtering on `id` and `group`, then use `igraph::cliques` to find the all combinations of size 4:

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)

dt <- setDT(df)[group %in% elig_groups]

combos <- matrix(
  as(
    names(
      unlist(
        cliques(
          graph_from_data_frame(
            dt[,datePlus := date + max_date_diff][
              dt,
              on = .(date > date, date <= datePlus),
              .(id, i.id, group, i.group)
            ][
              id != i.id & group != i.group
            ][,3:4 := NULL],
            FALSE
          ),
          n_elig_groups,
          n_elig_groups
        )
      )
    ), class(df$id)
  ),
  ncol = n_elig_groups, byrow = TRUE
)
```

There are 61 combinations:

```
dim(combos)
#> [1] 61  4
```

The first combination:

```
dt[id %in% combos[1,], 1:3]
#>     id       date group
#> 1:  39 2023-02-08     m
#> 2: 186 2023-02-10     d
#> 3: 323 2023-02-06     k
#> 4: 510 2023-02-13     p
```

Comment: Are you sure that all groups in your combinations are in elig_groups ?

Comment: Oops! Thank you for bringing that to my attention. Easy fix. My original answer would correspond to *all* groups being eligible. I guess that it worked well even with all the groups says something about the approach.

Comment: This is perfect & super-fast.  I haven't used `igraph` before but it's a really interesting application of the `cliques` function.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Logic is not better (making all combinations and keep the good ones), but with data.table it seems to be faster ..

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dfg <- df[group %in% elig_groups]
df2 <- dfg[group == elig_groups[1]]
df2[, one := 1]
for (i in elig_groups[-1]){
  current <- dfg[group == i][ , c(paste0("id", "_", i), 
                                  paste0("group", "_", i),
                                  paste0("date", "_", i),
                                  "one")
                              := .(id, group, date, 1)][, 4:7]
  df2 <- merge(df2, 
               current,
               by = "one",
               all = TRUE,
               allow.cartesian = TRUE)
    
  }

uni <- function (...){
  x <- list(...)
  sum(!duplicated(x))
      }
date.cols <- names(which(sapply(df2,is.Date)))
df2[, date_max := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = date.cols]
df2[, date_min := do.call(pmin, .SD), .SDcols = date.cols]

valid_combos2 <- df2[date_max - date_min <= days(max_date_diff)]
valid_combos2[, n_date := do.call(uni, .SD), by = seq_len(nrow(valid_combos2)),  .SDcols = date.cols]
valid_combos2 <- valid_combos2[n_date == 4]
```

And, more general, for the last line :

```
valid_combos2 <- valid_combos2[n_date == length(elig_groups)]
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you.  I use `data.table` so rarely but it's great in situations like this where speed and non-equi joins are needed.  I accepted @jblood94's answer because it's faster & more concise but this is really helpful for comparing the `dplyr` vs `data.table` approach side-by-side.  Thanks for the response!